# What does ‘though’ mean in “You sould probably go back to your home though man”?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice

What does **"though"** mean in the following sentence?

> You should probably go back to your home though man.

Comment: It means what it usually does - 'in spite of what was said before'.

Comment: Please provide details of the source of this quote

Answer (score 2):

> **Although/Though it's not late**, you should probably go back to your home.

> It's not late. You should probably go back to your home, **though**. (but not although)

We use *though* to say there is a contrast between 2 statements/clauses.